# Finding perfect number

Tags: c++, c

Finding perfect number in an integer range.

Firstly I wrote this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int ara[5] = { 6, 28, 496, 2128, 33550336 };
    int num, i, l, j, kase;

    scanf("%d", &kase);
    for (l = 0; l < kase; l++) {
        scanf("%d", &num);
        j = 1;
        for (i = 0; ara[i] <= num; i++) {
            printf("%d\n", ara[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but when I enter a larger number such as:

```
2//kase
40000000//input_1
```

outputs:

```
6
28
496
2128
33550336
1
0
7
```

76596795 (input_2) outputs:

```
6
28
496
2128
33550336
1
1
7
```

when I use if condition in loops it works perfectly well.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int ara[5] = { 6, 28, 496, 8128, 33550336 };
    int i, l, kase;
    int num;
    scanf("%d", &kase);
    for (l = 0; l < kase; l++) {
        scanf("%d", &num);
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if (ara[i] <= num) {
                printf("%d\n", ara[i]);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

as like: `1`//kase `40000000`//input outputs: `6, 28, 8128, 33550336.`

It'll be a great pleasure for me if anyone tell me some details about this.

Comment: Is there a reason for both the `c` and `c++` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in the first case, your control stays in the loop even as the value of `i` reaches and crosses `5`.

```
for(i = 0; ara[i] <= num; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", ara[i]);

    }
```

Suppose you input `40000000`. Then, all elements in the array satisfy the condition `ara[i] <= num`. But this is the sole condition for exiting the loop, due to which you stay in the loop `i=5,6,7...` and so on. The rest of the output values are garbage values.

In the second case, you are ensuring that `i<5`, so the problem is resolved. You could do this

```
 for(i = 0; i < 5 && ara[i] <= num; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", ara[i]);

    }
```